# 403 forbidden error when loading images in test server

Tags: 7, media, files

Am working with drupal7.When images are loading below error is showing in my test site console:

```
GET sites/default/files/styles/slideshow_full/public/plans/30989/main-image/contemporary_house_plan_westbrook_30-065_front.jpg?itok=TkUdCJQ5 403 (Forbidden)
```

When I paste the above URL in browser it is showing that ***"You are not authorised to access this page"*** error.

I checked all the permissions and all has 777.
But the same functionality  is working with my local site.Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical result of an incorrect url path.

That folder may/may not exist on the test server, but because it's outside of your user's folders, you 'don't have permission to access' it.

For example: Typical user's folders for cPanel are `/home/USER/` with the site root at `/home/USER/public_html`. But, typical for a local machine is `/var/www/...`.

So when you call `sites/default/...` from a local machine, it is possible that it's actually looking at `/var/www/sites/default/...`. When doing that on the test server, the path would be outside your user's folder and therefor no access permission.

It could be as simple as a missing `../` on your relative paths.
So you could try 1. adding `../` to the start of your paths and see if that takes it to the correct location.
or 2. Try explicitly setting the base url in your settings file `$base_url = 'http://foobar.com';` to force a starting point for relative paths.